# Error 500 when accessing a project's CI/CD on ubuntu 18

Tags: gitlab

I recently upgraded to the latest version of gitlab running ubuntu 18.

All is working well but now I'm getting error 500 on ci/cd on a project.

I saw similar posts but resolutions didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

What logs should I share for additional help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what does the error say?

Comment: Hi. Error 500 - Whoops, something went wrong on our end.

Comment: I resolved this by copying the old gitlab-secrets to the new gitlab server. Thanks.